# Can you use jQuery to manipulate html entered into a form text area?

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm wondering if I can use jQuery to recode HTML that's entered into a form. For example, I would like to "stripe" HTML table code that users manually enter into a form text area. If the textarea has an id=tablecode it does not work to do

```
$('textarea#tablecode tr:even').addClass('table_even');
```

Is there some way to use jQuery to manipulate the html that the users enter into the form box? or do I need to submit the form to the server and then use regular expressions in PHP to add my classes? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not directly since the contents of the text area are just text..

You can however read the value of the textarea and create an in-memory representation of that (*as long as it is valid html*), and process that.

```
$('#convert').click(function(){
  var $html = $( $('#tablecode').val() ).wrapAll('<div />').parent();

    // manipulate html
  $('tr:even', $html).addClass('table_even');

    //show altered html in another textarea with id=result
    $('#result').val($html.html());
});
```

**demo at** http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/f4FuG/

Answer (score 2):

try

```
var code = $('textarea#tablecode')[0].value;
var parsedHTML = $(code);
```

there you have a jQuery object wih the parsed HTML. Then you can manipulate it

```
$("tr:even", parsedHTML).addClass('table_even");
```

And optionally put the changes back in the textarea.

```
$('textarea#tablecode')[0].value = parsedHTML[0].outerHTML;
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to pull the text out of the textarea and create a DOM node out of it. (Then you could serialise it back into a string and put it back in the textarea, if required.)

Answer (score 0):

IDs apply to individual elements. They must be unique. Try changing the id to a class, and change your `#` to a `.`.

Answer (score 0):

textarea model is a plain text. So this selector `$('textarea#tablecode tr:even')` will simply  not work.

You will need to pass your text to html parser in order to get DOM. Then modify it. Then serialize it back to HTML.

This
[Robust and Mature HTML Parser for PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/292926/robust-mature-html-parser-for-php) can be useful.